# MATLAB find cell array substrings in a cell array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

Let's say we have a cell array of substrings `arrayOfSubstrings = {substr1;substr2}` and a cell array of strings `arrayOfStrings = {string1;string2;string3;stirng4}`. How can I get a logical map into the cell array of strings where at least one of the substrings is found? I have tried

`cellfun('isempty',regexp(arrayOfSubstrings ,arrayOfStrings ))`

and

`cellfun('isempty', strfind(arrayOfSubstrings , arrayOfStrings ))`

and some other permutations of functions, but am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that with both `strfind` and `regexp` is that you can't provide two cell arrays and have them automatically apply all patterns to all strings. You will need to loop through one or the other to make it work.

You can do this with an explicit loop

```
strings = {'ab', 'bc', 'de', 'fa'};
substrs = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

% First you'll want to escape the regular expressions
substrs = regexptranslate('escape', substrs);

matches = false(size(strings));

for k = 1:numel(strings)
    matches(k) = any(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(strings{k}, substrs)));
end

% 1  1  0  1
```

Or if you are for loop-averse you can use `cellfun`

```
cellfun(@(s)any(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(s, substrs))), strings)
% 1  1  0  1
```

### A Different Approach

Alternately, you could combine your sub-strings into a single regular expression

```
pattern = ['(', strjoin(regexptranslate('escape', substrs), '|'), ')'];
%   (a|b|c)

output = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(strings, pattern));
%   1  1  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you. I prefer the loop as it makes the code clearer, IMHO.

Comment: @Confounded It's going to likely be significant slower than the custom regex

Comment: "Custom regex"?

Comment: @Confounded The last part of my answer using the alternative approach

Comment: The last approach gives me an output array of different size compared to the loop.

Comment: @Confounded Are you sure that you used the right variable names? The output size is dictated by the size of the first input to `regexp`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R2016b or R2017a you can just use contains:

```
>> strings = {'ab', 'bc', 'de', 'fa'};
>> substrs = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
>> contains(strings, substrs)

ans =

  1×4 logical array

   1   1   0   1
```

Contains is also the fastest, especially if you use the new string datatype.

```
function profFunc()

    strings = {'ab', 'bc', 'de', 'fa'};
    substrs = {'a', 'b', 'c'};

    n = 10000;

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        substrs_translated = regexptranslate('escape', substrs);

        matches = false(size(strings));

        for k = 1:numel(strings)
            matches(k) = any(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(strings{k}, substrs_translated)));
        end
    end
    toc

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        cellfun(@(s)any(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(s, substrs))), strings);
    end
    toc

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        pattern = ['(', strjoin(regexptranslate('escape', substrs), '|'), ')'];
        output = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(strings, pattern)); %#ok<NASGU>
    end
    toc

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        contains(strings,substrs);
    end
    toc

    %Imagine you were using strings for all your text!
    strings = string(strings);

    tic;
    for i = 1:n
        contains(strings,substrs);
    end
    toc
end
```

Timing results:

```
>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 0.643176 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.007309 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.683643 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.050663 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.008177 seconds.
```