# MATLAB find number of replicates of substring array, in cell array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I have a MATLAB cell array of strings and a second array with partial strings:

```
base = {'a','b','c','d'}
all2 = {'a1','b1','c1','d1','a2','b2','c2','d2','q8','r15'}
```

The output is:

```
base = 

    'a'    'b'    'c'    'd'


all2 = 

    'a1'    'b1'    'c1'    'd1'    'a2'    'b2'    'c2'    'd2'    'q8'    'r15'
```

**Problem/Requirement**

If *any of* `'a1'`,`'b1'`,`'c1'`,`'d1'` AND *any of* `'a2'`,`'b2'`,`'c2'`,`'d2'` are present in the `all2` array, then return a variable `numb=2`.

If *any of* `'a1'`,`'b1'`,`'c1'`,`'d1'` AND *any of* `'a2'`,`'b2'`,`'c2'`,`'d2'` AND *any of* `'a3'`,`'b3'`,`'c3'`,`'d3'` are present in the `all2` array, then return a variable `numb=3`.

**Attempts**

1.

Based on `strfind`([this approach](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/50624-testing-for-the-presence-of-a-substring-in-a-cell-array-of-strings)), I tried `matches = strfind(all2,base);` but I got this error:

```
`Error using strfind`

`Input strings must have one row.`
....
```

2.

This [other](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/196719-find-strings-that-contain-multiple-substrings-at-the-same-time) approach using `strfind` seemed better but just gave me

```
fun = @(s)~cellfun('isempty',strfind(all2,s));
out = cellfun(fun,base,'UniformOutput',false)
idx = all(horzcat(out{:}));
idx(1,1) 

out = 

[1x10 logical]    [1x10 logical]    [1x10 logical]    [1x10 logical]


ans =

     0
```

Neither of these attempts have worked. I think my logic is incorrect.

3.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097086/matlab-find-cell-array-substrings-in-a-cell-array-of-strings) answer allows to find all indices of an array of partial strings in an array of strings. It returns:

```
base = regexptranslate('escape', base);
matches = false(size(all2));
for k = 1:numel(all2)
    matches(k) = any(~cellfun('isempty', regexp(all2{k}, base)));
end
matches
```

Output:

```
matches =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
```

My problem with this approach: How do I use the output `matches` to calculate `numb=2`? I am not sure if this is the most relevant logic for my specific question since it only gives matching indices.

**Question**

Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

**EDIT**

*Additional Information:*

The array `all2` WILL always be contiguous. A scenario of `all2 = {'a1','b1','c1','d1','a3','b3','c3','d3','q8','r15'}` is not possible.

Comment: What should happen when numbers aren't contiguous? Like `all2 = {'a1' 'a3' 'a4'};` Should that return `numb = 3`?

Comment: @gnovice `numb` should be `1` for that case

Comment: @gnovice I assume you meant `all2 = {'a1', 'a3', 'a4'};`. If so, then you are correct. If, `all2 = {'a1', 'a3' ,'a4'}` then the return should be `numb=3`. Using my example in the OP: If any of `'a1',...` AND any of `'a2',...` AND any of `'a3',...` are present in the `all2` array, then return a variable `numb=3`.

Comment: There's no `'a2, ...'` in his example...

Comment: Yes, there is no `a2`. However, there are still `a3` and `a4`. So both contiguous and non-contiguous are required.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Simplifying the base to `a`, for `num=3` you should have `a1 AND a2 AND a3`, not `a1 AND a3 AND a4`.

Comment: Do you just want the number of unique suffixes to `base`?

Comment: I want the number of unique suffixes to *any* element in `base`.

Comment: That's not at all what your logic statement says

Comment: Are the elements of `base` always going to be one character?

Comment: Yes, base will always be one character.

Comment: Thanks to @gnovice for pointing out the difference between contiguous and non-contiguous arrays `all2`. I have added an EDIT to the OP stating that the array `all2` **must** be contiguous at all times. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regex to find the unique suffixes to the `base` elements:

```
base = {'a','b','c','d'};
all2 = {'a1','b1','c1','d1','a2','b2','c2','d2', 'a4', 'q8','r15'};

% Use sprintf to build the expression so we can concatenate all the values
% of base into a single string; this is the [c1c2c3] metacharacter.
% Assumes the values of base are going to be one character
%
% This regex looks for one or more digits preceeded by a character from
% base and returns only the digits that match this criteria.
regexstr = sprintf('(?<=[%s])(\\d+)', [base{:}]);

% Use once to eliminate a cell array level
test = regexp(all2, regexstr, 'match', 'once');

% Convert the digits to a double array
digits = str2double(test);

% Return the number of unique digits. With isnan() we can use logical indexing
% to ignore the NaN values
num = numel(unique(digits(~isnan(digits))));
```

Which returns:

```
>> num

num =

     3
```

---

If you need continuous digits then something like this should be valid:

```
base = {'a','b','c','d'};
all2 = {'a1','b1','c1','d1','a2','b2','c2','d2', 'a4', 'q8','r15'};

regexstr = sprintf('(?<=[%s])(\\d+)', [base{:}]);
test = regexp(all2, regexstr, 'match', 'once');
digits = str2double(test);

% Find the unique digits, with isnan() we can use logical indexing to ignore the
% NaN values
unique_digits = unique(digits(~isnan(digits)));

% Because unique returns sorted values, we can use this to find where the
% first difference between digits is greater than 1. Append Inf at the end to
% handle the case where all values are continuous.
num = find(diff([unique_digits Inf]) > 1, 1);  % Thanks @gnovice :)
```

Which returns:

```
>> num

num =

     2
```

---

Breaking down the [`regexp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) and [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) lines: Because we know that `base` only consists of single characters, we can use the [`[c1c2c3]` metacharacter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#inputarg_expression), which will match any character inside the brackets. So if we have `'[rp]ain'` we'll matche `'rain'` or `'pain'`, but not `'gain'`.

`base{:}` returns what MATLAB calls a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). Adding the brackets concatenates the result into a single character array.

Without brackets:

```
>> base{:}

ans =

    'a'


ans =

    'b'


ans =

    'c'


ans =

    'd'
```

With brackets:

```
>> [base{:}]

ans =

    'abcd'
```

Which we can insert into our expression string with `sprintf`. This gives us `(?<=[abcd])(\d+)`, which matches one or more digits preceeded by one of either `a, b, c, d`.

Comment: I think this solution works. I am still thinking about the contiguous/non-contiguous part. I updated the OP but I may need to delete that. Still thinking....

Comment: I've added a solution with a continuous restriction

Comment: Yes, it *needs* to be contiguous. Ok,a thanks for separating these out. This is very specific and I had not initially thought of the 2 cases. This works for me.

Comment: Ok, except for the first 3 lines, I seem to understand the other lines....they seem clear. Just the first 3 are a little confusing. Mainly line 1...could you explain how you used `sprintf` to assemble the [expression](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#inputarg_expression) required by `regexp`?

Comment: I've added a breakdown of the regex, hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: Yup! Answered. Great answer!